# Where to store configuration URL variable in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an external ecommerce link that varies based based on environment (testing and production systems).

Where should it go in Rails?

Possibilities include:

- a conditional directly in the template, on the button (not a good solution, IMO)
- database (though there's no model for this so it would be a specific case possibly over-generalized)
- application.rb (which I believe is not recommended for this purpose)
- environment-specific application configs
- initializer
- view helper
- YAML file
- (external) environment variable
- etc.

Where would this typically go in Rails?

Some of these keep the template clean, but put a very specific case far away from the place it's used.

Answer (score 3):

Configuration data like this should always be stored in a configuration file. I have the below line in all my rails applications:

```
# config/application.rb
config.app_config = Rails.application.config_for(:app_config)
```

You can read more about it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-config_for

Answer (score 3):

I store configuration variables like these in YAML files and then load them into the app's configuration in `config/application.rb`. I believe this is a standard practice.

### Example

I configure a URL for something in a config file. For example, this config file is `config/client.yml`:

```yaml
defaults: &defaults
  url: 'localhost:8080'

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

Then I make it available in my app by adding this line to `config/application.rb`:

```rb
config.client = config_for(:client)
```

That line roughly translates to, "Load the configuration specified in `config/client.yml` and make it available in the app as `Rails.configuration.client`".

Now, I can get the URL anywhere in my app via `Rails.configuration.client['url']`.

### So three steps:

1. Create `.yml` file in `config/`
2. Declare the file as a config in `config/application.rb`
3. Access the config in the app via `Rails.configuration`